# Question about voltage in a digital logic circuit

Tags: voltage, digital-logic

I'm a relative newcomer to electronics and have what's probably an embarrassingly easy question. I've designed the circuit below in TinkerCad and while I understand the 2.00 volt drop across the powered LED and the 2.49 volt drop across the 220 ohm resistor, I'm confused as to why there's a 510 millivolt drop across the input and output of the 74HC08 AND gate.  Any insight into what I'm not understanding here would be greatly appreciated and my apologies that this is more fundamental than many of the usual questions asked in this forum.  Thanks! [image]

Comment: Please research what constitutes a schematic diagram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 74HC08 output has a MOSFET transistor between the positive supply and the output pin, and that transistor has some resistance.  The output current to feed the LED will pass through that transistor, so there will be some voltage drop across the transistor, making the output voltage somewhat less than the positive supply.

Comment: Thanks!  Very easy to understand and much appreciated.

Comment: I should have mentioned that a similar effect will occur for a Low output driving an LED connected to the positive supply - the gate output will be a little above Ground.

Answer (score 2):

The outputs of real semiconductors are not ideal. The outputs of the 74HC logic family aren't ideal switched. The more current you draw from an output, the more the voltage will depart from its ideal value. This is typically a property of the entire logic family: all 74HC outputs will act similarly. You need to look at the datasheet for that logic family: http://web.mit.edu/6.111/www/s2007/datasheets/hctfamspec.pdf

The figure of interest is the VOH level at -4mA load current (negative since it's flowing out of the pin), at 4.5V supply. You can then shift the values by 0.5V to get some idea of what would be expected at the same current at 5V (more or less). The datasheet only specifies behavior at 4.5V and 6V supply voltage.

The 74HC logic family output levels are not specified for 11mA output current. What the actual chips will do depends on the basic properties shared by all MOS transistors, as well as on the size of the output driver transistors and their threshold voltage and transconductance. The datasheet specifies output high voltage (VOH) only up to -4mA output current for standard outputs (not bus driver outputs). At -4mA, you'll expect about 0.2V drop across the output transistor typical, 0.5V maximum. Since you're loading the output with 11mA, the 0.5V drop is not unexpected.

This behavior will depend on the transconductance of the output transistors in the chip, as well as on the gate threshold voltage. As the load increases, the transistor will transition from acting like a resistor to acting like a current source. You can figure the transconductance by shorting the output to ground in a pulsed fashion (a short of a short duration, say 1ms), assuming the gate voltage to be -Vcc, and taking a guess at the threshold voltage. I would imagine it to be between -1V and -2.5V but have not looked at it recently. You can determine that voltage by measuring the supply current vs input voltage to any of the gate inputs, and notice at what voltage below the supply rail the supply current goes up: the P transistor will begin to conduct at that point. Use at least 6V supply for this measurement. With due care, you will be able to measure subthreshold conduction of the P input transistor, and get a solid threshold voltage value out of it.

The output pin model that TinkerCad is using to emulate the behavior of a 74HC08 is likely giving you some "more or less typical" behavior, but the chip manufacturer doesn't guarantee any of it usually, since you're outside of the current range for which the datasheet specifies ("guarantees") the voltage drop. The behavior you will observe on actual physical 74HC chip will vary per manufacturing process parameter spread and slight implementation differences between various sources for those ubiquitous chips.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!  Very helpful and I think I can wrap my head around most of it.  Thanks again, much appreciated.